# After submiting a php form I get empty window and no e-mail

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

**Update:**

I've added echo $errors to the end of my code. Now I am getting that all fields are required although all are filled:

```
} else {
  echo $errors;
}
```

I've created a simple php e-mail form with this example ([link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html)). And jQuery form validator ([link](http://www.formvalidator.net/)).

Now what I get after submiting a form is just a empty "contact-form-handler.php" page.

You can see the form live at: mantasmilka.com/#contactPage

What could be the problem? Below is my code.

**contact-form-handler.php**

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'mantas@mantasmilka.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['infoname'])  ||
   empty($_POST['infocompany']) ||
   empty($_POST['infoemail']) ||
   empty($_POST['infophone']) ||
   empty($_POST['infodescription'])
   )
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$jobtype = $_POST['jobtype'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$location = $_POST['location'];

$infoname = $_POST['infoname'];
$infocompany = $_POST['infocompany'];
$infoemail = $_POST['infoemail'];
$infophone = $_POST['infophone'];

if (isset($_POST['infodescription'])) {
    $infodescription = $_POST['infodescription'];
}

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$infoemail))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Jobtype: $jobtype \n Budget: $budget \n Location: $location \n Name: $infoname \n Company: $infocompany \n E-mail: $infoemail \n Phone: $infophone \n ".
"Message \n $infodescription";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $infoemail";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
// header('Location: http://www.mantasmilka.com/index.php');
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
} else {
  echo $errors;
}
?>
```

**my form in index.php:**

```
  <form id="contactform" method="post" name="contact_form" action="contact-form-handler.php">
    <div class="left">
      <fieldset class="jobtype">
        <legend>Job type</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="project" value="project" required>
          <label for="project">Project</label>
        <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="part-time" value="part-time" >
          <label for="part-time">Part-time</label>
        <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="full-time" value="full-time" >
          <label for="full-time">Full-time</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="budget">
        <legend>Budget</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="budget5k" value="budget5k" required>
          <label for="budget5k">5k &euro; ></label>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="budget10k" value="budget10k" >
          <label for="budget10k">5k - 10k &euro;</label>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="budget15k" value="budget15k" >
          <label for="budget15k">15k &euro; <</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="location">
        <legend>Location</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="location" id="locremote" value="locremote" required>
          <label for="locremote">Remote</label>
        <input type="radio" name="location" id="loclocal" value="loclocal" >
          <label for="loclocal">Local with relocation</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <fieldset class="contactinfo">
        <legend>Your Contact Info</legend>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="infoname" id="infoname" value="" required data-validation="alphanumeric">
          <label for="infoname">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="infocompany" id="infocompany" value="" required data-validation="alphanumeric">
          <label for="infocompany">Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="infoemail" id="infoemail" value="" required data-validation="email">
          <label for="infoemail">E-mail</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="infophone" id="infophone" value="" required data-validation="number">
          <label for="infophone">Phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder textarea">
          <textarea name="infodescription" form="contact_form" rows="4" required></textarea>
          <label for="infodescription">Message</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-holder submit">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" required/>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Check for errors in your script by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script.

Comment: use `echo $errors` at the end of php script.

Comment: I've added both of those things. Now it echos Error: all fields are required although I am filling all of my fields...

Comment: You can also view all of your post data with `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST,1) . '</pre>';` - using `print_r` wrapped in `<pre>` tags is quite a nice way to view objects and scalars when PHP debugging.

Comment: Also, in your mark-up, try using `required="required"` on your `input` and other form elements. I have found this to work best cross-browser, and also for dynamic form validation with jQuery (I know some JS developers prefer vanilla JS).

Comment: why you can't use javascript validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text field should look like this don't put form tag in here

```
<textarea name="infodescription" rows="4" required></textarea>
```

in php make the if statement like this the first ( opens the if statement the last ) closes it and take not of how i used the other brackets

```
if(
   (empty($_POST['infoname']))  ||
   (empty($_POST['infocompany'])) ||
   (empty($_POST['infoemail'])) ||
   (empty($_POST['infophone'])) ||
   (empty($_POST['infodescription']))
   )
     {
      $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to solve the problem is:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    if($('#infodescription').val() == '')
    {
     alert('Description is required');
     return false;
    }
    //add other validation
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
});
```

By this you can avoid the unwanted server load.